# AWS S3 Storage's Object Lock settings not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an AWS S3 bucket with Object Lock settings for Compliance Mode. While I upload a file in the bucket (And the in the File settings I can see that the Object Lock is enabled in compliance mode), I was able to delete the file. I am not sure, as per the AWS documentation, even the root user cannot delete the file with Compliance Mode Object Lock.

Please help if I am misunderstood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> **Important**
>
> Object locks apply to individual object versions only.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lock-overview.html

Take a look at [How Do I See the Versions of an S3 Object?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/view-object-versions.html) and switch your console view to "show" object versions.  You should find that you didn't actually delete the locked object version.

What you did when you "deleted" the object was create a delete marker.

> A delete marker is a placeholder (marker) for a versioned object that was named in a simple `DELETE` request. Because the object was in a versioning-enabled bucket, the object was not deleted. The delete marker, however, makes Amazon S3 behave as if it had been deleted.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeleteMarker.html

With the console in the "hide" versions mode, delete requests are "simple `DELETE` requests" as mentioned above.

With the console in the "show" versions mode, delete operations you attempt are, instead, on specific versions of the object, and you should find that you are unable to delete any versions with object locks.

You'll also find that you can apparently overwrite an object with a new upload, but again you can't actually do that, because uploading an object with the same key in a versioned bucket (and enabling versioning is mandatory for object lock to work) doesn't overwrite the object -- it just creates a newer version of the object, leaving older versions intact.

When the top (newest, current) version of an object is a delete marker, the object disappears from the console and isn't included in ListObjects requests sent to the bucket via the API, but does appear in ListObjectVersions API requests.  The "show/hide" setting is only applicable to your personal console view, it doesn't change actual bucket behavior.

The timestamps on object versions can't be altered, so locking an object version not only prevents deletion of the object contents, it also preserves a record of when that object was originally created.  "Overwriting" an object creates a new version with a new timestamp, and the timestamps on the versions prove what content existed in the bucket at any given point in time.

Comment: Then what is the difference between just having versions enabled on the object and having the object lock? In versioned bucket also you can see the delete markers and original versions.

Comment: Even with Versioning enabled, you can still permanently delete an object. In the console, you just need to enable the "Show versions" option for that and select the specific version that you want to remove. With Object Lock enabled, that same operation will fail.